# IntelliJ: Theme Not Applying to Files Outside of src Folder

Tags: intellij-idea, themes, intellij-plugin

On IntelliJ I'd like to have my Material Theme apply to files outside of the src folder. If I create/open a project folder, then my theme gets applied to all the files under the src folder, so all my text is color coded. If I simply open up a file in IntelliJ the theme is not applied to the file.

As I'm not allowed to embed images here are the links for the imagers for when the file is in and not in the src folder:

[In src folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bGXG.png)

[Color coded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l171i.png)

[Not in src folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WgWx.png)

[Not color coded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vX6UF.png)

Comment: This is expected behavior. External files are opened as plain text files and basic language highlighting is used.

Comment: @y.bedrov Is there any way to change this?